# Tracking data does not propagate to www.google.com/analytics

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

I am developing a iPad Application which used to search photos using Flicker API, with XCode 4.5 and iOS 6.0

I simply follow the guidelines provided by Google-Analytics-SDK 1.5.1 for iOS and add **GANTracker.h** and **libGoogleAnalytics.a** and running my app on iPad Simulator 6.0.

I have written the following code in **- AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

static NSString *const kAnalyticsAccountId = @"UA-35865309-1";
static const NSInteger kDispatchPeriodSeconds = 10;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:kAnalyticsAccountId
                                       dispatchPeriod:kDispatchPeriodSeconds
                                             delegate:self];
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setDebug:YES];
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setDryRun:NO];
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setSampleRate:100];
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setAnonymizeIp:YES];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                     name:@"iOS Application"
                                                    value:@"Demo Flicker"
                                                withError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Set Custom Variable At Index failed :: %@",error);
}
else {}

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"APP Launching"
                                     action:@"No Action"
                                      label:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"
                                      value:-1
                                  withError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Track event failed :: %@",error);
}

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/app_entry_point"
                                     withError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Track page view failed :: %@",error);
}
return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - GANTrackerDelegate Methods

-(void) hitDispatched:(NSString *)hitString {
NSLog(@"Hit Dispatched: %@", hitString);
}

-(void) trackerDispatchDidComplete:(GANTracker *)tracker eventsDispatched:(NSUInteger)hitsDispatched eventsFailedDispatch:(NSUInteger)hitsFailedDispatch {
NSLog(@"Dispatch completed (%u OK, %u failed)",hitsDispatched, hitsFailedDispatch);
}
```

After run the app on iPad Simulator 6.0, console prints the following:

```
2012-10-26 00:21:26.835 DemoFlicker[737:11303] dispatch called
2012-10-26 00:21:26.836 DemoFlicker[737:11303] dispatching 1 hits
2012-10-26 00:21:26.836 DemoFlicker[737:11303] GET /__utm.gif?    utmwv=4.9.1mi&utmn=1254389404&utmt=event&utme=5(Photo%20Search*Searching*textFieldShouldReturn)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=768x1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmac=UA-35865309-1&utmp=%2FHome%20Page&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1252676167.1351163416.1351235761.1351236010.8%3B&aip=1&utmht=1351236076832&utmqt=10004 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com
User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.5.1 (iPad Simulator; U; CPU iPhone OS 6.0 like Mac OS X; en-us)

2012-10-26 00:21:27.004 DemoFlicker[737:11303] Hit Dispatched: /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.9.1mi&utmn=1254389404&utmt=event&utme=5(Photo%20Search*Searching*textFieldShouldReturn)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=768x1024&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmac=UA-35865309-1&utmp=%2FHome%20Page&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1252676167.1351163416.1351235761.1351236010.8%3B&aip=1&utmht=1351236076832&utmqt=10004
2012-10-26 00:21:27.005 DemoFlicker[737:11303] Dispatch completed (1 OK, 0 failed)
2012-10-26 00:21:36.835 DemoFlicker[737:11303] dispatch called
2012-10-26 00:21:36.836 DemoFlicker[737:11303] ...nothing to dispatch
2012-10-26 00:21:48.757 DemoFlicker[737:12303] Found 10 photos matching Flower
```

Now, The problem is with propagation of tracking data on host www.google.com/analytics. Actually i can not see the tracking data on the www.google.com/analytics.

Where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: How long have you waited?  It can take a day for the data to populate in google analytics.

Comment: @Luck i am waiting from last 2 days.